# What's the Solidity statement to print data to the console?

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, events, logs, console

Sometimes it would be really helpful to be able to see string representations of variable values in the Geth console, like of argument values in functions. Can I somehow print them to the Geth console?

Answer (score 26):

You are most likely looking for [Events](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#events). Not only do they help with debugging, but they are useful in normal production code.

Events are declared like functions, like so:

```
event VoteCast(address voter, uint votes, bool inFavor);
```

Then somewhere (for example, in a vote counting function):

```
function vote(bool inFavor) {
    var votes = shares[msg.sender];
    // ...
    emit VoteCast(msg.sender, votes, inFavor);
}
```

In javascript, a contract object has an event method, which can be used to read events when they happen. In fact, it can read events that happened in the past.

```
var voteCast = someContract.voteCast();
voteCast.watch(function(err, result) {/* some callback */});
// Alternately, to get the events all at once.
voteCast.get(function(err, result) /* some other callback* /)
```

Events have a number of quirks, which are too many to get into detail here. Nonetheless, they're an integral part of high-level dapp work.

Answer (score 16):

EDIT: `logX` is deprecated and doesn't appear in Solidity 0.8+ documentation. The bellow example is only working if using Solidity up to version 0.7.6 and should now be replaced by Events or Solidity libraries enabling the use of `console.log()` inside your contract code.

Since my first answer, many projects improved the debug experience:

- https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-logger-example

  ```
  import "truffle/Console.sol";
  ```
- https://hardhat.org/tutorial/debugging-with-hardhat-network.html
- https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hardhat_console.html

  ```
  import "hardhat/console.sol";
  ```

---

### Deprecated answer

Print doesn't exist in Solidity. Use the [logX statement](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#low-level-interface-to-logs) as indicated in the manual instead.

Comment: The log statements are really low level. One is better off using specific events.

Comment: Agree they're low-level but can be useful especially for temporary debugging to quickly see a value in IDEs that support log statements and pretty-print their parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned `geth console`, you can try `console.log()` for debugging purposes:

> **console.log** ("Your debug message" + debug.object);

This is possible because `geth` supports `web3.js`

Comment: this is js way , not solidity

Comment: @MaxLXJ `print` is not supported by Solidity as it supports Events-driven paradigm, but since it leverages JavaScript syntax it is quite handy to use `console.log` for debug purposes. But this is not recommended for Production/Live usage as Solidity written contract will be distributed across nodes, and using [Events](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#events) will be ideal.

Comment: It's true that is not solidity, but probably it's what most people want: an easy way to print something in the console. This works if you write the console.log in the console and not in the solidity code.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri could you provide an example of using console.log within solidity? This seems like a major miss in the language implementation

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ 's link gives an example to print an event to the console

Comment: @GeoffLangenderfer Yes, and they are using `console.log(result);` to print the result to console.